# Cloudera Hadoop datanode not starting

Tags: hadoop

I have installed CDH 5 in a single node Ubuntu 14.04 LTS machine, in pseudo distributed mode, using the cloudera guide : http://www.cloudera.com/content/www/en-us/documentation/enterprise/5-3-x/topics/cdh_qs_yarn_pseudo.html

Previously I had installed MRv1. It was running fine. Then I decided to migrate to YARN.

I used the un-installation process of MRv1 mentioned in the tutorial and then continued with the YARN installation. But after I start all services, I see all services starting except my Data node.

Even when I am checking the status of Data node in the web console, it shows number of live nodes as zero.

I have tried to start the Data node separately with the service command but it shows:

> "Failed to start Hadoop datanode. Return value: 1".

I have tried formatting the Name node and restarting all services, but with no help. Can you help me understand what has gone wrong?

Answer (score 1):

1. Did you look at the namenode and datanode logs? anything interesting there?
2. Check if there are stale/old datanode processes left over from the previous setup, and kill them. Use 'ps' and not 'jps' as jps has issues and may not show all existing processes. After cleaning up, re-format the namenode and start it up. This solved it for me quite a few times in the past.

Comment: I found the following error in the datanode log:      """"""""Problem connecting to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:8020
2015-11-14 09:54:49,792 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.Storage: Lock on /var/lib/hadoop-hdfs/cache/hdfs/dfs/data/in_use.lock acquired by nodename 1088@monamie-VPCEG3AEN   """""""""""What must have been the problem?